# Typicode My json server shows "404 error Oops, can't find db.json file on main or master branch. Try to create one and retry."

Tags: github, rest, json-server

I had configured JSON server and created a db.json file and even added in some data, everything worked fine so I pushed it to Github, I replaced my localhost JSON server port URL with the one of typicode i.e https://my-json-server.typicode.com/myGithubUsername/myRepository/resource and tested again, still, things worked but after changing my GitHub repository to private am now getting this when I try to access the resource!

`404 error Oops, can't find db.json file in myGithubUsername/myRepository/resource on main or master branch. Try to create one and retry.`

Answer (score 0):

> I changed my GitHub repository back to public and it solved the
> problem but this was for my employees so it shouldn't remain public, I
> don't know if anyone has a better way to fix this, but this worked!